# What is the meaning of this Modulus output?

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

Quick question, what is the meaning of the $\mathbb{c}_1$ subscript in the output of Modulus (shown as an image below)?

[image]

I understand there are two solutions to this linear congruence, 6 and 15 (6+9), so I can guess $\mathbb{c}_1$ might denote something related to that.

Comment: ``C[1]`` denotes an arbitrary (integer) constant. There are not only two solutions! There are infinitely many solutions, such as $x\in \{..., -21, -12, -3, 6, 15, 24, 33, ...\}$.

Comment: @Domen Thank you!

Comment: @Domen We are working modulo 18 though, which collapses this infinite set into $\{6, 15\}$.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ah, I see! I mistakenly thought this was equivalent to $4x=16 \; (\text{mod }18)$, but the option ``Modulus`` in fact defines a modular _domain_ of solutions. Perhaps a useful note to the author: use ``Solve`` to get two solutions ``Solve[4 x == 6, x, Modulus -> 18] (* {{x -> 6}, {x -> 15}} *)``.

Comment: @Domen I think that deserves an answer (the use of `Solve`).

Comment: @Domen It seems like `Solve` does not automatically give me a least residue answer without specifying some sort of bounds on $x$ or the equation — it still gives me an output with infinite solutions: $\{\{x \to 6 + 9\mathbb{c}_1\}\}$.

Comment: @Jason1923 - This is version specific. With v12.2 and later, `Solve` gives `{{x -> 6}, {x -> 15}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`C[i]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) appears in the result, it usually means that the solution is valid for any value of `C[i]`.

In this case, `6 + 9 c` is a solution for any `c`. If you put in all possible values of `c`, you will see that `6 + 9 c` is either 6 or 15:

```
Union@Table[Mod[6 + 9 c, 18], {c, 0, 17}]
(* {6, 15} *)
```